# @fortawesome/fontawesome-free not working in vite react

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have installed `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` in Vite React and imported it in `Navbar.jsx` but it shows this error,

```
SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@fortawesome_fontawesome-free.js?v=84581a2b' does not provide an export named 'default' (at Navbar.jsx:5:1)
```

**Navbar.jsx:**

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import { Button } from "./components/Button";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './css/Navbar.css'
import  {FontAwesomeIcon}  from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';
import { faBars, faTimes } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';

function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

  const showButton = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1200) {
      setButton(false);
    } else {
      setButton(true);
    }
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    showButton();
    window.addEventListener("resize", showButton);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", showButton);
    }
  }, []);
  
 

  return (
    
    <>
       
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="navbar-container">
          <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
            <img
              src="./images/Logo-2.png"
              width="200"
              height="50"
              alt="Linesofbinary"
            />
          </Link>
          <div className="menu-icon"   onClick={handleClick}>
            {/* <i className={click ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"} /> */}
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={click ? faTimes : faBars} />
          </div>
          <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to="/" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                to="/services"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                Code
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                to="/about"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                About
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                to="/product"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                Practice
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li>
              <Link
                to="/sign-up"
                className="nav-links-mobile"
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
              >
                Sign Up
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {button && <Button buttonStyle="btn--outline">SIGN UP</Button>}
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

**The error:**

```
SyntaxError: The requested module
'/node_modules/.vite/deps/@fortawesome_fontawesome-free.js?v=84581a2b'
does not provide an export named 'default' (at Navbar.jsx:5:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons):

here are the steps you need to do:

install the folowing packages:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

then change your imports to:

```
import { faBars, faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
```

if you do not like the solid icon, you can change '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons' to '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'